# Установка последней версии golang

Tags: golang

Я  поставил на виртуалке Ubuntu 16.04, а в ней при устанвоке go предлагается версия 1.6. Устанавливал apt-get`ом. Последняя же версия 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apt-get позволяет ставить лишь старую версию, к сожалению. Чтобы поставить последнюю, нужно зайти на сайт [golang](https://golang.org/dl/) и скачать последнюю версию. Затем, её нужно положить куда-нибудь в удобное место. Например, в `~/home`. Другой вариант -- сделать там папочку `programs`. Затем необходимо прописать путь `~/home/go/bin` в `PATH` (через двоеточие) и сделать что-то в духе `export PATH`.

Т.е. это выглядеть должно примерно так:

> PATH=$PATH:~/home/go/bin
>
> export $PATH

Comment: Так быстро ответил на собственный вопрос? Жаль принять нельзя сразу же, верно?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Я на него ответил сразу. У меня спросили про то, почему это так. Я решил написать. Вероятнее всего, у кого-нибудь такой вопрос уже возникал.

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич Что вам не понравилось?

Comment: Надо взять на вооружение. Самому себе задавать вопросы и сразу же на них отвечать :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич по-моему от этого все только в плюсе остаются

Comment: Этак много чего можно навыдумывать. И да, Ваше решение не самое оптимальное. Своё писать не буду... Думаю, не оценят тут :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это не я придумал. Я это подцепил у одного из участников сообщества

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич, [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) статья про это в справке, может пригодится.